# How to show the many side in a one-to-many relation as a table using Entity Framework scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, one-to-many, scaffolding

After choose a team I need to show the players in this team.

I think the better way is to show a table of players in the create/edit/show team views.

This is my model:

```
public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name", AutoGenerateField = false)]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Team", AutoGenerateField = false)]
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name", AutoGenerateField = false)]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Players")]
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

But entity framework scaffold does not create a table inside teams views. It just create a combobox to choose the team in the player views.

I searched on the internet but not found anything about that. How could I force scaffold to generate this table? Or it is necessary to create this table manually?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework 6+ and C# in a asp.net mvc project.

What I what to show is something like this:

Team

Name: Survivors

Players

```
 _________
| Name  v 
 _________
| Bill    
| Louis   
| Zoey    
| Francis 
 _________
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to show the table by editing my Team view manually. Just added that:

```
 <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>


    @foreach (var player in Team.Players)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => player.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Players") |
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new  { controller = "Players", id = player.PlayerId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new  { controller = "Players", id = player.PlayerId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new  { controller = "Players", id = player.PlayerId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Not the easyest way, but works.